# Adding ASPX components from Code behind using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement which adds html/aspx components from code behind. The components can be either Check box or Radio button and options for them comes from the Database.
So what is the best approach to do this. Is user control helps here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally determine and add such controls via the page `OnInit` overload or `Page_Init` event, and be sure you do it on *all* requests, including postbacks.

Define local variables to hold the objects you may create (it could be a `List<>` if you don't know how many will exist ahead of time), and instantiate them as any other object, set their properties, and then add them to the `Controls` collection of the container item they should be in; By default, they will be added to the end of the container, but you can `Insert` them instead of `Add` if you like.

Assuming you re-create them like this every time, and do it during `Init`, you can then access them - including viewstate, if applicable - from the `Load` event/overload.

Comment: I think this requires DB call on each postback as my control are coming from DB. What if the user selected some option and did the postback then if i bind those controls again, user selection wont persist right?. then i need to save the user selected options and restore them. Is there any approach i can use which doesnt needs adding controls on every postback?

Comment: What ever you need to do to select the controls to create, do it where I noted above; in `Init`. Make sure to set all the same properties you would normally set in the ASPX - especially including `Name`. If you do it at the right time, on *all* postbacks, it *will* be populated with user-supplied values just like any other control on the page.